# Error in Web Service created by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, axis

I'm getting this error when testing my web service created by exlipse using Axis 1.4

```
- <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
- <soapenv:Body>
- <soapenv:Fault>
<faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode> 
<faultstring>java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException</faultstring> 
- <detail>
 <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ahernandez-PC</ns1:hostname> 
 </detail>
 </soapenv:Fault>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The file in which the error is present (I believe so atleast) is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://cancelaciones.vital" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://cancelaciones.vital" xmlns:intf="http://cancelaciones.vital" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->
 <wsdl:types>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://cancelaciones.vital" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <element name="sellado">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="llave" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="certificado" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="xmlString" type="xsd:string"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
   <element name="selladoResponse">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="selladoReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>

   <wsdl:message name="selladoRequest">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:sellado" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="selladoResponse">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:selladoResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:portType name="Cancelacion">

      <wsdl:operation name="sellado">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:selladoRequest" name="selladoRequest">

       </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:selladoResponse" name="selladoResponse">

       </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:portType>

   <wsdl:binding name="CancelacionSoapBinding" type="impl:Cancelacion">

      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

      <wsdl:operation name="sellado">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="selladoRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="selladoResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:binding>

   <wsdl:service name="CancelacionService">

      <wsdl:port binding="impl:CancelacionSoapBinding" name="Cancelacion">

         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/CancelacionesWS/services/Cancelacion"/>

      </wsdl:port>

   </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CanelacionesWeb</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Axis Admin Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AdminServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Add or link to the whole trace, not just the line you think shows the error.

Comment: I edited it, to show the complete error log, I get a different error now however I'm still lost.

Comment: InvocationTargetException: URL of service is wrong or unresponsive

Comment: I edited and included the wsdl, I'm not sure what URL could be wrong.

Comment: The request's URL. How are you trying to consume web service? (code, please)

Comment: right now, I'm using eclipse web service explorer to do the tests.

Comment: So you follow this sequence: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M4/tutorials/WebServiceExplorer.html ? How far can you go? Did you actually manage to see the operations?

Comment: all the way to invoking the method, in fact that error I displayed is the result that method returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty much like you have a WSDL file that allows you to know the operations but the actual server where you should have your services is down. Check that the services are available

Comment: If you open http://localhost:8080/CancelacionesWS/services/Cancelacion on your preffered web browser, does it show anything?

Comment: yeah, it shows a splash page generated by axis, that says "Hi there, this is an AXIS service!" etc etc

Answer (score 0):

It may be the exception cause due to missing configurations in web.xml file. At first, WSDL searches for the config in web.xml and the .wsdl file you generated as SOAP service. if it mismatches InvocationTargetException might be thrown.

Comment: I included web.xml, I'm not sure if any entry is missing.